# Ubuntu WiFi/Shutdown problems on Lattepanda

Tags: drivers, wireless, shutdown, broadcom, reboot

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed on a [Lattepanda](http://lattepanda.com) SBC. OOB most things work fine. The graphics run at full speed, disk read/write are on par, USB sound works great (internal does not).

I'm running into problems with the WiFi/Bluetooth card (which works great with Windows 10). The internal WiFi is not detected, and I'm forced to use a USB WiFi dongle.
card details: Broadcom 802.11abgn Wireless SDIO Adapter (SD\VID_02d0&PID_a94d
)

Also, when trying to restart or shut down, Ubuntu gets stuck at the splash screen. I assume this is a problem with ACPI or something along those lines, but I don't know.

Lattepanda details:
Intel Atom x5-Z8300
4GB RAM,
64GB EMMC internal storage

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert regarding Linux and BIOS but facing some issues to get Android working completely on LattePanda 4/64 myself.

So far it boots and runs fine except for bluetooth and sound.

At least I found [this following post which allowed me to enable wifi on my LattePanda](http://www.lattepanda.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=58&start=90#p2327)

Regarding sound I found the following tips to try this evening:

- Enter BIOS Setup
- Go to **Chipset -> South Bridge -> Audio Configuration**
- Change LPE Audio Support to LPE Audio PCI mode

Source: https://github.com/libretro/Lakka/issues/398

Comment: Another option regarding sound:

Comment: http://ronubo.blogspot.de/2012/03/enabling-sound-on-android-x86-devices.html?m=1

Comment: You might want to [edit] and integrate the info from the second option into your answer as comments can be deleted for a number of reasons and links sometimes go down without warning.